# Shielding app from library leaks

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

I have to use a function from a shared library which leaks some small amount of memory (Let's assume I can't modify the library). Unfortunately, I have to call this function huge number of times which obviously makes this leak catastrophic.

Is there any method to fix this problem? If yes, is there a fast method of doing this? (The function must be called few hundred thousand times, the leak becomes problematic after about 10k times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a couple of approaches, but I don't know what will work for you.

- Switch to a garbage-collecting memory allocator like [Boehm's gc](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).  This can sweep up those leaks, and may even be a performance gain because `free()` becomes a no-op.
- `exit()`: The Ultimate Deallocator.  Fork off a subprocess, run it 10k times, pass the results back to the parent process.  Apache's web server does this to contain damage from third-party library leaks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this easier than rewriting the function yourself, but you could write your own small memory allocator specific for your task, which would look somewhat the following way:

***(it should replace default memory allocation calls and this is done for the functions in your library too).***

1) You should have a possibility to enter the *leak-reverting mode*, which, for example, disposes everything allocated in this mode.

2) Before your function processes something, enter that *leak-reverting mode* and exit it upon the function finishes.

*Basically, if the dependencies in your code aren't too tight, this would help.*

---

Another way would be making another application and pairing it with the main. When the second one exits, the memory would be automatically disposed. *You may want to see how `googletest` framework runs it's child test and how the pipes are being constructed there.*

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  If you have time, you can rewrite the function yourself.  Catastrophic usually means this is the way to go.  One other possibility, can you load and unload the library (like a .so)?  It's possible that this will release the leaked memory.

Comment: Maybe I've done something wrong, but my test showed that heap memory persists after unload.